# How to keep appending subdocuments in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to do a bulk insert in MongoDB using PyMongo.
I have millions of product/review documents to insert into MongoDB. Here is the structure of the document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("553858a14483e94d1e563ce9"),
    "product_id" : "B000GIKZ4W",
    "product_category" : "Arts",
    "product_brand" : "unknown",
    "reviews" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2012-01-09T00:00:00Z"),
            "score" : 3,
            "user_id" : "A3DLA3S8QKLBNW",
            "sentiment" : 0.2517857142857143,
            "text" : "The ink was pretty dried up upon arrival. It was...",
            "user_gender" : "male",
            "voted_total" : 0,
            "voted_helpful" : 0,
            "user_name" : "womans_roar \"rohrra\"",
            "summary" : "Cute stamps but came with dried up ink"
        }
    ],
    "product_price" : "9.43",
    "product_title" : "Melissa & Doug Deluxe Wooden Happy Handle Stamp Set"
}
```

There can be multiple reviews for a single product. The requirement is to insert one document per product_id and keep appending more reviews as subdocument in the reviews array. Can you please provide some pointers on how this can be achieved? Also, will be nice to do implement bulk insert for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will be nice to do implement bulk insert for performance.

In pymongo can execute [**Ordered bulk write operations**](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/bulk.html#ordered-bulk-write-operations)  or [**Unordered Bulk Write Operations**](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/bulk.html#unordered-bulk-write-operations)

> The requirement is to insert one document per product_id and keep appending more reviews as subdocument in the reviews array

You can use the [**`update_one`**](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) or [**`update_many`**](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many) (Pymongo 3 or newer) or [**`update`**](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update) method to [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) subdocument to the `reviews` array

```python
collection.update_one({"_id": <doc_id>}, {"$push": {"reviews": <subdocument>}})
```

or

```python
collection.update({"_id": <doc_id>}, {"$push": {"reviews": <subdocument>}})
```

To insert need document if no document matches the given criteria use `upsert` option

```python
collection.update({"_id": <doc_id>}, {"$push": {"reviews": <subdocument>}}, upsert=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The modified_count from UpdateResult object returned is None and it does not insert any data into MongoDB. I have to do an upsert where if product_id is not found then I add the whole product document, else I just append the reviews part (subdocument) to the existing product document. Please suggest a way in which this can be achieved.

Comment: @Randeep to insert new document if `product_id` not found use `upsert=True`. Edited my answer

Comment: Yep, I got that figured out now. Its working :)
Thank you for your timely response.

Comment: How does this work with multiple reviews being given? Doesn't this only add 1 subdocument?

Comment: I you want to add multiple reviews, then you also need to use the [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) operator. Otherwise it will add the array to the reviews array instead of extending it